# Cant instantiate a softprocessor design in quartus because of compile errors(Error10170)

Tags: fpga, quartus

I've made a design in platform design in quartus ver 18.0 and I want to instantiate it in a template design I made for the MAX10DE10 lite development kit
I try to compile it and it gives me this error:

> Error (10170): Verilog HDL syntax error at DE10_LITE_Golden_Top.sv(2)
> near text: "(";  expecting ";". Check for and fix any syntax errors
> that appear immediately before or at the specified keyword. The Intel
> FPGA Knowledge Database contains many articles with specific details
> on how to resolve this error. Visit the Knowledge Database at
> https://www.altera.com/support/support-resources/knowledge-base/search.html
> and search for this specific error message number.

I made a soft processor design in platform design called core and the core_inst.v verilog file is as follows:

```
core u0 (
        .altpll_1_areset_conduit_export   (<connected-   to-    altpll_1_areset_conduit_export>),   //`   altpll_1_areset_conduit.export
         .altpll_1_locked_conduit_export   (<connected-to-altpll_1_locked_conduit_export>),   //   altpll_1_locked_conduit.export
        .clk_clk                          (<connected-to-clk_clk>),                          //                       clk.clk
        .clk_0_clk                        (<connected-to-clk_0_clk>),                        //                     clk_0.clk
        .pio_0_external_connection_export (<connected-to-pio_0_external_connection_export>), // pio_0_external_connection.export
        .pio_1_external_connection_export (<connected-to-pio_1_external_connection_export>), // pio_1_external_connection.export
        .reset_reset_n                    (<connected-to-reset_reset_n>),                    //                     reset.reset_n
        .reset_0_reset_n                  (<connected-to-reset_0_reset_n>),                  //                   reset_0.reset_n
        .altpll_0_c1_clk                  (<connected-to-altpll_0_c1_clk>)                   //               altpll_0_c1.clk
    );
```

The code for the template is:

```
// ============================================================================
//   Ver  :| Author                 :| Mod. Date :| Changes Made:
//   V1.1 :| Alexandra Du           :| 06/01/2016:| Added Verilog file
// ============================================================================


//=======================================================
//  This code is generated by Terasic System Builder
//=======================================================

`define ENABLE_ADC_CLOCK
`define ENABLE_CLOCK1
`define ENABLE_CLOCK2
`define ENABLE_SDRAM
`define ENABLE_HEX0
`define ENABLE_HEX1
`define ENABLE_HEX2
`define ENABLE_HEX3
`define ENABLE_HEX4
`define ENABLE_HEX5
`define ENABLE_KEY
`define ENABLE_LED
`define ENABLE_SW
`define ENABLE_VGA
`define ENABLE_ACCELEROMETER
`define ENABLE_ARDUINO
`define ENABLE_GPIO
    
        
module DE10_LITE_Golden_Top(

    //////////// ADC CLOCK: 3.3-V LVTTL //////////
`ifdef ENABLE_ADC_CLOCK
    input                       ADC_CLK_10,
`endif
    //////////// CLOCK 1: 3.3-V LVTTL //////////
`ifdef ENABLE_CLOCK1
    input                       MAX10_CLK1_50,
`endif
    //////////// CLOCK 2: 3.3-V LVTTL //////////
`ifdef ENABLE_CLOCK2
    input                       MAX10_CLK2_50,
`endif

    //////////// SDRAM: 3.3-V LVTTL //////////
`ifdef ENABLE_SDRAM
    output          [12:0]      DRAM_ADDR,
    output           [1:0]      DRAM_BA,
    output                      DRAM_CAS_N,
    output                      DRAM_CKE,
    output                      DRAM_CLK,
    output                      DRAM_CS_N,
    inout           [15:0]      DRAM_DQ,
    output                      DRAM_LDQM,
    output                      DRAM_RAS_N,
    output                      DRAM_UDQM,
    output                      DRAM_WE_N,
`endif

    //////////// SEG7: 3.3-V LVTTL //////////
`ifdef ENABLE_HEX0
    output           [7:0]      HEX0,
`endif
`ifdef ENABLE_HEX1
    output           [7:0]      HEX1,
`endif
`ifdef ENABLE_HEX2
    output           [7:0]      HEX2,
`endif
`ifdef ENABLE_HEX3
    output           [7:0]      HEX3,
`endif
`ifdef ENABLE_HEX4
    output           [7:0]      HEX4,
`endif
`ifdef ENABLE_HEX5
    output           [7:0]      HEX5,
`endif

    //////////// KEY: 3.3 V SCHMITT TRIGGER //////////
`ifdef ENABLE_KEY
    input            [1:0]      KEY,
`endif

    //////////// LED: 3.3-V LVTTL //////////
`ifdef ENABLE_LED
    output           [9:0]      LEDR,
`endif

    //////////// SW: 3.3-V LVTTL //////////
`ifdef ENABLE_SW
    input            [9:0]      SW,
`endif

    //////////// VGA: 3.3-V LVTTL //////////
`ifdef ENABLE_VGA
    output           [3:0]      VGA_B,
    output           [3:0]      VGA_G,
    output                      VGA_HS,
    output           [3:0]      VGA_R,
    output                      VGA_VS,
`endif

    //////////// Accelerometer: 3.3-V LVTTL //////////
`ifdef ENABLE_ACCELEROMETER
    output                      GSENSOR_CS_N,
    input            [2:1]      GSENSOR_INT,
    output                      GSENSOR_SCLK,
    inout                       GSENSOR_SDI,
    inout                       GSENSOR_SDO,
`endif

    //////////// Arduino: 3.3-V LVTTL //////////
`ifdef ENABLE_ARDUINO
    inout           [15:0]      ARDUINO_IO,
    inout                       ARDUINO_RESET_N,
`endif

    //////////// GPIO, GPIO connect to GPIO Default: 3.3-V LVTTL //////////
`ifdef ENABLE_GPIO
    inout           [35:0]      GPIO
`endif
);



//=======================================================
//  REG/WIRE declarations
//=======================================================




//=======================================================
//  Structural coding
//=======================================================



endmodule
```

---

And the entire code with the instantiation is:

```
core u3 (
        .altpll_1_areset_conduit_export   (<connected-to-altpll_1_areset_conduit_export>),   //   altpll_1_areset_conduit.export
        .altpll_1_locked_conduit_export   (<connected-to-altpll_1_locked_conduit_export>),   //   altpll_1_locked_conduit.export
        .clk_clk                          (<connected-to-clk_clk>),                          //                       clk.clk
        .clk_0_clk                        (<connected-to-clk_0_clk>),                        //                     clk_0.clk
        .pio_0_external_connection_export (<connected-to-pio_0_external_connection_export>), // pio_0_external_connection.export
        .pio_1_external_connection_export (<connected-to-pio_1_external_connection_export>), // pio_1_external_connection.export
        .reset_reset_n                    (<connected-to-reset_reset_n>),                    //                     reset.reset_n
        .reset_0_reset_n                  (<connected-to-reset_0_reset_n>),                  //                   reset_0.reset_n
        .altpll_0_c1_clk                  (<connected-to-altpll_0_c1_clk>)                   //               altpll_0_c1.clk
    );




// ============================================================================
//   Ver  :| Author                 :| Mod. Date :| Changes Made:
//   V1.1 :| Alexandra Du           :| 06/01/2016:| Added Verilog file
// ============================================================================


//=======================================================
//  This code is generated by Terasic System Builder
//=======================================================

`define ENABLE_ADC_CLOCK
`define ENABLE_CLOCK1
`define ENABLE_CLOCK2
`define ENABLE_SDRAM
`define ENABLE_HEX0
`define ENABLE_HEX1
`define ENABLE_HEX2
`define ENABLE_HEX3
`define ENABLE_HEX4
`define ENABLE_HEX5
`define ENABLE_KEY
`define ENABLE_LED
`define ENABLE_SW
`define ENABLE_VGA
`define ENABLE_ACCELEROMETER
`define ENABLE_ARDUINO
`define ENABLE_GPIO





module DE10_LITE_Golden_Top(

    //////////// ADC CLOCK: 3.3-V LVTTL //////////
`ifdef ENABLE_ADC_CLOCK
    input                       ADC_CLK_10,
`endif
    //////////// CLOCK 1: 3.3-V LVTTL //////////
`ifdef ENABLE_CLOCK1
    input                       MAX10_CLK1_50,
`endif
    //////////// CLOCK 2: 3.3-V LVTTL //////////
`ifdef ENABLE_CLOCK2
    input                       MAX10_CLK2_50,
`endif

    //////////// SDRAM: 3.3-V LVTTL //////////
`ifdef ENABLE_SDRAM
    output          [12:0]      DRAM_ADDR,
    output           [1:0]      DRAM_BA,
    output                      DRAM_CAS_N,
    output                      DRAM_CKE,
    output                      DRAM_CLK,
    output                      DRAM_CS_N,
    inout           [15:0]      DRAM_DQ,
    output                      DRAM_LDQM,
    output                      DRAM_RAS_N,
    output                      DRAM_UDQM,
    output                      DRAM_WE_N,
`endif

    //////////// SEG7: 3.3-V LVTTL //////////
`ifdef ENABLE_HEX0
    output           [7:0]      HEX0,
`endif
`ifdef ENABLE_HEX1
    output           [7:0]      HEX1,
`endif
`ifdef ENABLE_HEX2
    output           [7:0]      HEX2,
`endif
`ifdef ENABLE_HEX3
    output           [7:0]      HEX3,
`endif
`ifdef ENABLE_HEX4
    output           [7:0]      HEX4,
`endif
`ifdef ENABLE_HEX5
    output           [7:0]      HEX5,
`endif

    //////////// KEY: 3.3 V SCHMITT TRIGGER //////////
`ifdef ENABLE_KEY
    input            [1:0]      KEY,
`endif

    //////////// LED: 3.3-V LVTTL //////////
`ifdef ENABLE_LED
    output           [9:0]      LEDR,
`endif

    //////////// SW: 3.3-V LVTTL //////////
`ifdef ENABLE_SW
    input            [9:0]      SW,
`endif

    //////////// VGA: 3.3-V LVTTL //////////
`ifdef ENABLE_VGA
    output           [3:0]      VGA_B,
    output           [3:0]      VGA_G,
    output                      VGA_HS,
    output           [3:0]      VGA_R,
    output                      VGA_VS,
`endif

    //////////// Accelerometer: 3.3-V LVTTL //////////
`ifdef ENABLE_ACCELEROMETER
    output                      GSENSOR_CS_N,
    input            [2:1]      GSENSOR_INT,
    output                      GSENSOR_SCLK,
    inout                       GSENSOR_SDI,
    inout                       GSENSOR_SDO,
`endif

    //////////// Arduino: 3.3-V LVTTL //////////
`ifdef ENABLE_ARDUINO
    inout           [15:0]      ARDUINO_IO,
    inout                       ARDUINO_RESET_N,
`endif

    //////////// GPIO, GPIO connect to GPIO Default: 3.3-V LVTTL //////////
`ifdef ENABLE_GPIO
    inout           [35:0]      GPIO
`endif
);



//=======================================================
//  REG/WIRE declarations
//=======================================================




//=======================================================
//  Structural coding
//=======================================================



endmodule
```

Answer (score 0):

To make the instantiation of the core the block should be putted just above the endmodule like this

```
// ============================================================================
//   Ver  :| Author                 :| Mod. Date :| Changes Made:
//   V1.1 :| Alexandra Du           :| 06/01/2016:| Added Verilog file
// ============================================================================


//=======================================================
//  This code is generated by Terasic System Builder
//=======================================================

`define ENABLE_ADC_CLOCK
`define ENABLE_CLOCK1
`define ENABLE_CLOCK2
`define ENABLE_SDRAM
`define ENABLE_HEX0
`define ENABLE_HEX1
`define ENABLE_HEX2
`define ENABLE_HEX3
`define ENABLE_HEX4
`define ENABLE_HEX5
`define ENABLE_KEY
`define ENABLE_LED
`define ENABLE_SW
`define ENABLE_VGA
`define ENABLE_ACCELEROMETER
`define ENABLE_ARDUINO
`define ENABLE_GPIO





module DE10_LITE_Golden_Top(

    //////////// ADC CLOCK: 3.3-V LVTTL //////////
`ifdef ENABLE_ADC_CLOCK
    input                       ADC_CLK_10,
`endif
    //////////// CLOCK 1: 3.3-V LVTTL //////////
`ifdef ENABLE_CLOCK1
    input                       MAX10_CLK1_50,
`endif
    //////////// CLOCK 2: 3.3-V LVTTL //////////
`ifdef ENABLE_CLOCK2
    input                       MAX10_CLK2_50,
`endif

    //////////// SDRAM: 3.3-V LVTTL //////////
`ifdef ENABLE_SDRAM
    output          [12:0]      DRAM_ADDR,
    output           [1:0]      DRAM_BA,
    output                      DRAM_CAS_N,
    output                      DRAM_CKE,
    output                      DRAM_CLK,
    output                      DRAM_CS_N,
    inout           [15:0]      DRAM_DQ,
    output                      DRAM_LDQM,
    output                      DRAM_RAS_N,
    output                      DRAM_UDQM,
    output                      DRAM_WE_N,
`endif

    //////////// SEG7: 3.3-V LVTTL //////////
`ifdef ENABLE_HEX0
    output           [7:0]      HEX0,
`endif
`ifdef ENABLE_HEX1
    output           [7:0]      HEX1,
`endif
`ifdef ENABLE_HEX2
    output           [7:0]      HEX2,
`endif
`ifdef ENABLE_HEX3
    output           [7:0]      HEX3,
`endif
`ifdef ENABLE_HEX4
    output           [7:0]      HEX4,
`endif
`ifdef ENABLE_HEX5
    output           [7:0]      HEX5,
`endif

    //////////// KEY: 3.3 V SCHMITT TRIGGER //////////
`ifdef ENABLE_KEY
    input            [1:0]      KEY,
`endif

    //////////// LED: 3.3-V LVTTL //////////
`ifdef ENABLE_LED
    output           [9:0]      LEDR,
`endif

    //////////// SW: 3.3-V LVTTL //////////
`ifdef ENABLE_SW
    input            [9:0]      SW,
`endif

    //////////// VGA: 3.3-V LVTTL //////////
`ifdef ENABLE_VGA
    output           [3:0]      VGA_B,
    output           [3:0]      VGA_G,
    output                      VGA_HS,
    output           [3:0]      VGA_R,
    output                      VGA_VS,
`endif

    //////////// Accelerometer: 3.3-V LVTTL //////////
`ifdef ENABLE_ACCELEROMETER
    output                      GSENSOR_CS_N,
    input            [2:1]      GSENSOR_INT,
    output                      GSENSOR_SCLK,
    inout                       GSENSOR_SDI,
    inout                       GSENSOR_SDO,
`endif

    //////////// Arduino: 3.3-V LVTTL //////////
`ifdef ENABLE_ARDUINO
    inout           [15:0]      ARDUINO_IO,
    inout                       ARDUINO_RESET_N,
`endif

    //////////// GPIO, GPIO connect to GPIO Default: 3.3-V LVTTL //////////
`ifdef ENABLE_GPIO
    inout           [35:0]      GPIO
`endif
);



//=======================================================
//  REG/WIRE declarations
//=======================================================




//=======================================================
//  Structural coding
//=======================================================

core u3 (
        .altpll_1_areset_conduit_export   (ARDUINO_IO[2]),   //   altpll_1_areset_conduit.export
        .altpll_1_locked_conduit_export   (ARDUINO_IO[3]),   //   altpll_1_locked_conduit.export
        .clk_clk                          (MAX10_CLK1_50),    //                       clk.clk
        .clk_0_clk                        (ADC_CLK_10),      //                     clk_0.clk
        .pio_0_external_connection_export (LEDR),           // pio_0_external_connection.export
        .pio_1_external_connection_export (sw),             // pio_1_external_connection.export
        .reset_reset_n                    (ARDUINO_RESET_N),                    //                     reset.reset_n
        .reset_0_reset_n                  (ARDUINO_RESET_n),                  //                   reset_0.reset_n
        .altpll_0_c1_clk                  ()                 //               altpll_0_c1.clk
    );

endmodule
```

This design compiles and disappears the error 10170

[image]